# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' using reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am having trouble in my webpack, eventhough i install all requirements and put it on resolve.fallback, did i miss something? please help thanks

This is my webpack.

```
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const singleSpaDefaults = require("webpack-config-single-spa-react");
const path = require("path");
module.exports = (webpackConfigEnv, argv) => {
  const defaultConfig = singleSpaDefaults({
    orgName: "App",
    projectName: "FirstApp",
    webpackConfigEnv,
    argv,
    resolve: {
      fallback: {
        "dist/custom-elements/index.mjs": "dist/custom-elements/index.js",
        "fs": false,
        "path": false,
        "os": false
      }
    },
  });

  return merge(defaultConfig, {
    // modify the webpack config however you'd like to by adding to this object
    externals: [
      'react',
      'react-dom',
      '@reach/router',
      '@mui/material'
    ],
    devServer:{https:true}
  });
};
```

> ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 24:11-24 Module not found:
> Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> 'C:\Users\Ronald\Desktop\App\App-FirstApp\node_modules\dotenv\lib'  @
> ./src/views/Operation\App\App-FirstApp/Operation\App\App-FirstApp.js
> 8:0-28 10:0-13  @ ./src/views/home/Homepage.js 3:0-65 21:43-58  @
> ./src/root.component.js 8:0-50 14:33-41 16:34-42  @
> ./src/ib-signal-threat.js 4:0-36 8:17-21
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 25:13-28 Module not found:
> Error: Can't resolve 'path' in
> 'C:\Users\Ronald\Desktop\App\App-FirstApp\node_modules\dotenv\lib'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
> - install 'path-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "path": false }  @ ./src/views/Operation\App\App-FirstApp/Operation\App\App-FirstApp.js
> 8:0-28 10:0-13  @ ./src/views/home/Homepage.js 3:0-65 21:43-58  @
> ./src/root.component.js 8:0-50 14:33-41 16:34-42  @
> ./src/ib-signal-threat.js 4:0-36 8:17-21
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 26:11-24 Module not found:
> Error: Can't resolve 'os' in
> 'C:\Users\Ronald\Desktop\App\App-FirstApp\node_modules\dotenv\lib'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
> - install 'os-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "os": false }  @ ./src/views/Operation\App\App-FirstApp/Operation\App\App-FirstApp.js
> 8:0-28 10:0-13  @ ./src/views/home/Homepage.js 3:0-65 21:43-58  @
> ./src/root.component.js 8:0-50 14:33-41 16:34-42  @
> ./src/ib-signal-threat.js 4:0-36 8:17-21
>
> ERROR in
> ./node_modules/@esri/calcite-components/dist/custom-elements/index.mjs
> 1:0-147 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> '@stencil/core/internal/client' in
> 'C:\Users\Ronald\Desktop\App\App-FirstApp\node_modules@esri\calcite-components\dist\custom-elements'
> Did you mean 'index.js'? BREAKING CHANGE: The request
> '@stencil/core/internal/client' failed to resolve only because it was
> resolved as fully specified (probably because the origin is strict
> EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs'
> file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type":
> "module"'). The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be
> fully specified. Add the extension to the request.  @
> ./node_modules/@esri/calcite-components/dist/custom-elements/bundles/notice.js
> 1:0-54 4:22-35 4:53-64  @
> ./node_modules/@arcgis/core/widgets/Feature.js 5:2284-2357  @
> ./node_modules/@arcgis/core/widgets/Popup.js 5:688-716 5:10241-10242
> @ ./node_modules/@arcgis/core/views/DOMContainer.js 5:492-527
> 5:3477-3478 5:5626-5627  @ ./node_modules/@arcgis/core/views/Map.js
> 5:644-693 5:1623-1624  @
> ./src/views/Operation\App\App-FirstApp/Operation\App\App-FirstApp.js
> 2:0-49 22:21-28  @ ./src/views/home/Homepage.js 3:0-65 21:43-58  @
> ./src/root.component.js 8:0-50 14:33-41 16:34-42  @
> ./src/ib-signal-threat.js 4:0-36 8:17-21
>
> 4 errors have detailed information that is not shown. Use
> 'stats.errorDetails: true' resp. '--stats-error-details' to show it.
>
> webpack 5.64.4 compiled with 4 errors and 1 warning in 10359 ms

Comment: The docs for `fallback` say that if you set it to false, a fallback will not be provided. Not that a fallback would help when you're trying to import `fs` on the client

Comment: then what should i do?

Comment: don't use dotenv on the client. It is not supported there

Comment: oh, so what should i used then?

Comment: That depends if you need the env variables set at build time or runtime

Comment: If it's at build time, you can use a plugin like `dotenv-webpack` to replace `process.env` statements with the actual values at build time (and/or replace env comparisons to `true` or `false`)

Comment: If it's at runtime, you will need to build into your app a way of passing configuration to the client. Either embedding it into the html response, or having an API endpoint to fetch config values on startup